# How not to print the same number for every row, I want different number at every position

Tags: java

I want to print numbers from 100000 to 1000000 separated by two spaces on each side of the number. I want to print 15 columns/ 15 unique numbers per line, but it's printing the same number for each line. How to fix this

```java
class practicex{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        pract();
    }

    static void pract(){
        for (long i=100000; i<1000000; i++){
            for(long q=0; q<15; q++){
                System.out.print("  " + i + "  ");
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Inside the inner `for` loop (in method `pract`) the value of variable `i` is not changing. Do you know how to use a debugger? If you do, then try using it to debug your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static void pract(){
        int ct=0;
        for (long i=100000; i<1000000; i++){
            //PUT THIS IS FIRST FOR LOOP  
            System.out.print( i + "  ");
            ct++;
            //EVERY 15 , print new line
            if (ct == 15) {
                ct=0;
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong loop. `i` is not changing. What you want to do is to have a combination of `while -> for`:

```java
static void pract(){
    int i = 100000;
    while(i<1000001){
        for(int q=0; q<15; q++){
            System.out.print("  " + i + "  ");
            i++;
            if (i > 1000000) break;
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: at the last line of the output,  this code is printing 1000001..........1000014. how not to print that

Comment: Corrected. I missed a line